# Can I get better prices for items by trading with different people

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I haven't upgraded barter much in Skyrim and I was wondering if that was the only way to get better prices for my loot or if nobles might spend more money for jewlerry or armour

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152879/whats-the-formula-for-merchant-price

Answer (score 14):

There are 2 ways to get 10% better Prices from vendors of the *opposite sex*.

1. Choose the `Allure` perk that is available with a `Speech` skill of 30.
2. [skyrim-dragonborn](/questions/tagged/skyrim-dragonborn)Choose the Ability `Lover's Insight` at the end of the `Black Book: The Winds of Change`.

Otherwise all vendors should give identical prices.

Comment: This answer is better than mine. Upvoted.

Comment: Just to check -- these effects cannot stack, right?

Comment: Lover's Insight stacks with Agent of Dibella so I would assume that Allure stacks with it as well for 20% increase. Not 100% sure but I'd bet it does.

Comment: @ChaseC - I wonder then, would stacking the second bonus give *"10% of the current 110%"* or *"20% of the original 100%"*. The former would give you 121% whereas the latter would give you 120%

Comment: @Robotnik Oh good lord more hypothesizing haha. I would say 120. The wiki said that lovers insight and agent of dibella stack to 120 because the 2 10%'s add together first, so I'm going with the same.

Answer (score 1):

No, specific Merchants do not pay more or less for certain items.

All Merchant information can be found [here!](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Merchants)

Answer (score 0):

To get better prices, enchant some gear with fortify barter or fortify speech.

For the speech part, a Dibella amulet will do.

For the prices part you can use thieves guild hood and Cicero's armor.